# File upload does not work

Tags: java, gwt, servlets

i created widget, and i added directly to root panel

```
public class FileUploadWidget extends VerticalPanel {
    public FileUploadWidget() {
        super();
        final FormPanel form = new FormPanel();

        form.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
        form.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
        form.setAction("/FileUpload"); 

        form.setWidget(this);

        final FileUpload fileUpload = new FileUpload();

        fileUpload.setName("uploadFormElement");  
        this.add(fileUpload);

        Label maxUpload = new Label();
        maxUpload.setText("Maximum upload file size: 1MB");
        this.add(maxUpload);

        Button button = new Button("Submit");
        button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                form.submit();

            }
        });
        this.add(button);

        form.addSubmitCompleteHandler(new SubmitCompleteHandler() {

            public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event) {
                Window.alert(event.getResults());

            }
        });
    }

}
```

i created servlet

```
public class FileUploadServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
    HttpServletResponse response) 
          throws ServletException, IOException { 
        response.setContentType("text/plain"); 

        FileItem uploadItem = getFileItem(request); //BREAKPOINT

        if (uploadItem == null) { 
          response.getWriter().write("NO-SCRIPT-DATA"); 
          return; 
        } 
        try {
            uploadItem.write(new File("newfile.txt"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            response.getWriter().write("ERROR");
        }

        response.getWriter().write("OK"); 
      } 

      private FileItem getFileItem(HttpServletRequest request) { 
        FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory(); 
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory); 

        try { 
          List items = upload.parseRequest(request); 
          Iterator it = items.iterator(); 
          while (it.hasNext()) { 
            FileItem item = (FileItem) it.next(); 
            if (!item.isFormField() 
                && "uploadFormElement".equals(item.getFieldName())) { 
              return item; 
            } 
          } 
        } catch (FileUploadException e) { 
          return null; 
        } 
        return null; 
      } 
     }
```

i put to my web.xml file mapping for servlet

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>FileUpload</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>my.web.app.GwtFileUpload.server.FileUploadServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
 ....
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FileUpload</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/FileUpload</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

now when i select file, and call submit, 
when i'm using firefox nothing really happened (all what i got is SubmitEvent), my breakpoint, which i marked in servlet code is never reached

when i try same code under chrome, it is comming into servlet, but it didn't find any file

can anyone explain me why there is so different behaviour, and how i can fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `FileUpload` widget wraps the `HTML`  element. This widget must be used with `FormPanel` if it is to be submitted to a server.
Thus it is necessary to add fileupload to the `FormPanel`. You have added it to directly the `Panel`.
Please replace the code

```
this.add(fileUpload);
```

to

```
form.add(fileUpload);
```

For more details please go thorough the link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/gwt/gwt_fileupload_widget.htm

Answer (score 2):

Add fileUpload control into `FormPanel`, because The `FileUpload` `widget` (those that implement HasName) will be submitted to the server if they are contained within this panel.

You are added `fileupload` into verticlepanel after doing `form.setWidget(this);`. do like

```
this.add(fileUpload);
form.setWidget(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the gwtupload library, it would save a lot of time writing your own code and would provide many features to your app like customize buttons, progress bar, file extensions, size limit, etc.

You have this [GettingStarted](https://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/wiki/GwtUpload_GettingStarted) and this [example](http://gwtupload.alcala.org/gupld/gwtuploadsample.MultipleUploadSample/MultipleUploadSample.html) page.